# forEach does not apply to dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very sorry in advance to post nearly 170 lines of JS code but cutting it down does not replicate the issue at all. The issue must be somewhere within this JS code.

I generate content through arrays/objects. This works absolutely fine. However, I cannot use `forEach` to manipulate the content of `spans` even though they should be part of the DOM tree.

What am I missing here?

```js
var language = document.documentElement.lang.toLowerCase();

/* ----- locailization_database.js ----- */
var DB_localization = [
  /* content */
  [
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2a',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'text',
      {
        de: `In Deutschland gibt es noch keine Gesetze, die artgerechte Haltung 
                     vorschreiben. Dennoch gibt es Richtlinien, nach welchen auch einige 
                     Veterinärämter handeln.`,
        us: 'not localized',
        en: 'not localized'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2b',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'tag',
      {
        de: '',
        us: '',
        en: ''
      },
      'br',
      ''
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2c',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'text',
      {
        de: `Die Tierärztliche Vereinigung für Tierschutz e.V. (TVT), das 
                     Bundesministerium für Ernährung und Landwirtschaft (BMEL) sowie der 
                     Sachkundenachweis für Kleinsäuger nach §11 Tierschutzgesetz, empfehlen ein 
                     Gehegemaß für alle Hamsterarten ab `
          /*<span class="minimum-surface-area"></span>
                               <span class="unit-lenght"></span>. */
          ,
        us: 'not localized',
        en: 'not localized'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2d',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'tag',
      {
        de: '',
        us: '',
        en: ''
      },
      'span',
      'minimum-surface-area'
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2e',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'tag',
      {
        de: '',
        us: '',
        en: ''
      },
      'span',
      'unit-lenght'
    ]
  ],

  /* measurement units */
  [
    [
      'DB_localization/units/lenght',
      document.querySelectorAll('.unit-lenght'),
      {
        de: 'cm',
        us: 'in',
        en: 'cm'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/units/surface-area-A',
      document.querySelectorAll('.unit-surface-area-A'),
      {
        de: 'm²',
        us: 'not localized',
        en: 'm²'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/units/surface-area-B',
      document.querySelectorAll('.unit-surface-area-B'),
      {
        de: 'cm²',
        us: 'ft²',
        en: 'cm²'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/units/factor',
      document.querySelectorAll('.unit-factor'),
      {
        de: 'x',
        us: 'x',
        en: 'x'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/units/minimum-surface-area',
      document.querySelectorAll('.minimum-surface-area'),
      {
        de: '100x50',
        us: '32x18',
        en: '100x50'
      }
    ],
  ]
];

/* ----- localization.js ----- */
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  /* loading unique elements */
  for (let i = 0; i < DB_localization[0].length; i++) {
    let DB_array_element = DB_localization[0][i][1],
      DB_array_type = DB_localization[0][i][2],
      DB_array_value = DB_localization[0][i][3][language];
    if (typeof DB_array_element !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof DB_array_type !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof DB_array_value !== 'undefined') {
      if (DB_array_type == 'text') {
        DB_array_element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', DB_array_value);
      }
      if (DB_array_type == 'tag') {
        let DB_array_tag = DB_localization[0][i][4],
          DB_array_class = DB_localization[0][i][5];
        let new_ele = document.createElement(DB_array_tag);
        DB_array_element.appendChild(new_ele);
        if (DB_array_class !== '') {
          new_ele.setAttribute('class', DB_array_class);
        }
      }
      array_path = DB_localization[0][i][0];
    } else {
    }

    if (i + 1 === DB_localization[0].length) {
      apply_units();
    }
  }

});

function apply_units() {
  /* applying the correct measurement units */
  for (let i = 0; i < DB_localization[1].length; i++) {
    let DB_array_element = DB_localization[1][i][1],
      DB_array_value = DB_localization[1][i][2][language];
    if (typeof DB_array_value !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof DB_array_element !== 'undefined') {
      DB_array_element.forEach(el => el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', DB_array_value));
      array_path = DB_localization[1][i][0];
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Einstreu-Rechner</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main class="py-l px-xl mx-auto mt-xl">

    <!-- ----- Section: Title ----- -->
    <h1 id="title"></h1>

    <!-- ----- Section: Description ----- -->
    <section id="description" title="Beschreibung über die Richtlininen des deutschen Standards">
      <p class="text-align-justify" id="text-block-1"></p>
      <p class="text-align-justify" id="text-block-2"></p>
      <h3 class="text-align-center" id="sub-title-1"></h3>
      <p class="text-align-center text-color-red" id="text-block-3"></p>
      <h4 class="text-align-center" id="sub-title-2"></h4>
    </section>

    <!-- More Content -->
    
    <p>This span works:</p>
    <span class="unit-lenght"><span>
```

Comment: Why are you using arrays with hard-coded array indexes in the code rather than objects with named properties?

Comment: I find it easier to `for loop` through instead

Comment: You find `DB_localization[1][i][1]` easier that `DB_localization.measurement[i].element`?

Comment: Your issue would seem to be that you are initialising `document.querySelectorAll('.unit-lenght'),` **before** you create all the spans that you want to select.

Comment: @Barmar there is more going on then just shown here. But that is not part of the issue and was left out. does your question has any relevance to the issue itself? (just asking in case I need to eleborate further).

Comment: The relevance is that I had a hard time understanding what the code does because I had to figure out what the array indexes pointed to. If an expert programmer (if I say so myself) can't understand your code, it's a sign that it's poorly written.

Comment: Once I decoded it I did post an answer. Satisfied?

Comment: yes, thank you I just checking if it works when implementing it. It was not meant as an offense. I just didn't wanted to include every single part as I thought it would distract from the actual issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll('.unit-lenght')` doesn't update when the DOM changes. Instead of calling `querySelectorAll()` when creating the array, put the selector in the `DB_localization` array and call `querySelectorAll()` when calling `forEach()`.

```js
var language = document.documentElement.lang.toLowerCase();

/* ----- locailization_database.js ----- */
var DB_localization = [
  /* content */
  [
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2a',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'text',
      {
        de: `In Deutschland gibt es noch keine Gesetze, die artgerechte Haltung 
                     vorschreiben. Dennoch gibt es Richtlinien, nach welchen auch einige 
                     Veterinärämter handeln.`,
        us: 'not localized',
        en: 'not localized'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2b',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'tag',
      {
        de: '',
        us: '',
        en: ''
      },
      'br',
      ''
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2c',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'text',
      {
        de: `Die Tierärztliche Vereinigung für Tierschutz e.V. (TVT), das 
                     Bundesministerium für Ernährung und Landwirtschaft (BMEL) sowie der 
                     Sachkundenachweis für Kleinsäuger nach §11 Tierschutzgesetz, empfehlen ein 
                     Gehegemaß für alle Hamsterarten ab `
          /*<span class="minimum-surface-area"></span>
                               <span class="unit-lenght"></span>. */
          ,
        us: 'not localized',
        en: 'not localized'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2d',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'tag',
      {
        de: '',
        us: '',
        en: ''
      },
      'span',
      'minimum-surface-area'
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/content/text-block-2e',
      document.querySelector('#text-block-2'),
      'tag',
      {
        de: '',
        us: '',
        en: ''
      },
      'span',
      'unit-lenght'
    ]
  ],

  /* measurement units */
  [
    [
      'DB_localization/units/lenght',
      '.unit-lenght',
      {
        de: 'cm',
        us: 'in',
        en: 'cm'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/units/surface-area-A',
      '.unit-surface-area-A',
      {
        de: 'm²',
        us: 'not localized',
        en: 'm²'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/units/surface-area-B',
      '.unit-surface-area-B',
      {
        de: 'cm²',
        us: 'ft²',
        en: 'cm²'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/units/factor',
      '.unit-factor',
      {
        de: 'x',
        us: 'x',
        en: 'x'
      }
    ],
    [
      'DB_localization/units/minimum-surface-area',
      '.minimum-surface-area',
      {
        de: '100x50',
        us: '32x18',
        en: '100x50'
      }
    ],
  ]
];

/* ----- localization.js ----- */
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  /* loading unique elements */
  for (let i = 0; i < DB_localization[0].length; i++) {
    let DB_array_element = DB_localization[0][i][1],
      DB_array_type = DB_localization[0][i][2],
      DB_array_value = DB_localization[0][i][3][language];
    if (typeof DB_array_element !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof DB_array_type !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof DB_array_value !== 'undefined') {
      if (DB_array_type == 'text') {
        DB_array_element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', DB_array_value);
      }
      if (DB_array_type == 'tag') {
        let DB_array_tag = DB_localization[0][i][4],
          DB_array_class = DB_localization[0][i][5];
        let new_ele = document.createElement(DB_array_tag);
        DB_array_element.appendChild(new_ele);
        if (DB_array_class !== '') {
          new_ele.setAttribute('class', DB_array_class);
        }
      }
      array_path = DB_localization[0][i][0];
    } else {
    }

    if (i + 1 === DB_localization[0].length) {
      apply_units();
    }
  }

});

function apply_units() {
  /* applying the correct measurement units */
  for (let i = 0; i < DB_localization[1].length; i++) {
    let DB_array_element = document.querySelectorAll(DB_localization[1][i][1]),
      DB_array_value = DB_localization[1][i][2][language];
    if (typeof DB_array_value !== 'undefined' &&
      typeof DB_array_element !== 'undefined') {
      DB_array_element.forEach(el => el.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', DB_array_value));
      array_path = DB_localization[1][i][0];
    } else {
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Einstreu-Rechner</title>
</head>

<body>

  <main class="py-l px-xl mx-auto mt-xl">

    <!-- ----- Section: Title ----- -->
    <h1 id="title"></h1>

    <!-- ----- Section: Description ----- -->
    <section id="description" title="Beschreibung über die Richtlininen des deutschen Standards">
      <p class="text-align-justify" id="text-block-1"></p>
      <p class="text-align-justify" id="text-block-2"></p>
      <h3 class="text-align-center" id="sub-title-1"></h3>
      <p class="text-align-center text-color-red" id="text-block-3"></p>
      <h4 class="text-align-center" id="sub-title-2"></h4>
    </section>

    <!-- More Content -->
    
    <p>This span works:</p>
    <span class="unit-lenght"><span>
```